# How do I add something written on a JList to JTextfield by clicking on a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, jlist

I'm making a program to insert users into a PostgreSQL database using NetBeans, and recently I've faced a problem that I'm asking myself if it's possible to fix? Basically, I wanted to select something from a `JList` and put it into a `JTextField`. Is it possible? I've tried a lot of ways to do it and nothing's working.

[here's the interface i did:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6utkM.png)

[Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyOst.png)

[Code2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1eMw.png)

[Code3:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ljJw.png)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple *Swing* application that displays a [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), a [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and a [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

When you click on the `JButton` the selected item in the `JList` is copied to the `JTextField`. (Refer to method `setTextFieldText` in the below code.)

Note that the [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) is implemented using a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ShirleyB {
    private JList<String> list;
    private JTextField textField;

    private void buildAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shirley B");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTextField(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createList(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButton(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButton() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Add");
        button.addActionListener(this::setTextFieldText);
        panel.add(button);
        return panel;
    }

    private JScrollPane createList() {
        String[] items = new String[]{"Zeroth",
                                      "First",
                                      "Second",
                                      "Third",
                                      "Last"};
        list = new JList<>(items);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JPanel createTextField() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(textField);
        return panel;
    }

    private void setTextFieldText(ActionEvent event) {
        String selection = list.getSelectedValue();
        textField.setText(selection);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new ShirleyB().buildAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```